# What is the Time format for this "date": "2014-08-20 00:00:00 -0500"?

Tags: java, android, date

I tried converting this date the following way:

```
SimpleDateFormat fromFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss SSSZ");
```

but I got:

```
 java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-09-20 00:00:00 -0500" (at offset 20)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That "-0500" is the offset from UTC, in RFC822 format. You just want `Z`, without the `SSS`.

The [Android `SimpleDateFormat` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) have it like this in the table:

- Symbol: Z
- Meaning: time zone (RFC 822)
- Kind: (Time Zone)
- Example: `Z/ZZ/ZZZ`:-0800 `ZZZZ`:GMT-08:00 `ZZZZZ`:-08:00

I would also personally specify a locale, as a matter of course: this is a machine-readable format rather than a human-oriented format, so I'd usually specify `Locale.US`:

```
SimpleDateFormat format  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z",
                                                Locale.US);
String text = "2014-08-20 00:00:00 -0500";
System.out.println(format.parse(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24334342/642706) is correct.

## Standard Date-Time Format

Here is some example code showing how to transform your string into compliance with [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

```
String inputRaw = "2014-08-20 00:00:00 -0500";
String input = inputRaw.replaceFirst( " ", "T" ).replaceFirst( " ", "" ); // Replace first SPACE with a 'T', and delete second SPACE.
// input is "2014-08-20T00:00:00-0500".
```

## Joda-Time

You can pass that compliant string directly to the constructor of DateTime in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Ditto for the equivalent in the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time).

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ); // Specify it rather than have JVM's default applied.
DateTime dateTimeMontréal = new DateTime( input, timeZone );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeMontréal.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "inputRaw: " + inputRaw );
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTimeMontréal: " + dateTimeMontréal );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
```

When run…

```
inputRaw: 2014-08-20 00:00:00 -0500
input: 2014-08-20T00:00:00-0500
dateTimeMontréal: 2014-08-20T01:00:00.000-04:00
dateTimeUtc: 2014-08-20T05:00:00.000Z
```